# How to create custom password attribute in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I want to create a password attribute for Contact entity in  CRM portal for my organization.
I can add it as a "custom attribute" through the designer, and can display it on the form for user to input. 
However, the problem is that, the attribute, and a field on the form designer are in plain Text format, whereas, I want them as a strict password. That means, they must not be human-readable, and possibly, should be stored in encrypted format.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering why you need to store a password in CRM...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rely on `Field Level Security`, more details here:

[How Field Security Can Be Used to Control Access to Field Values in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309608.aspx)

but I suggest a different approach: instead saving the password, why don't store its hash (MD5 or SHA1) and check it inside the authentication process?

Comment: I agree that hashing the password is the best answer.  The portal even includes a field for storing your salt when you hash the password.  I just got done modifying the portal to do this exact thing and it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not documented, but you can add this to the form XML for your password field - put this as a child of the < control> node that you want to be a password:

```
<parameters>
  <IsPassword>true</IsPassword>
<parameters>
```

If you look at the forms for Mailbox and EmailServerProfile you'll see this being done.

All this does is display ******* instead of the password - the password is still stored as plain text and anyone with read permissions on the entity can get the value using an SDK call.